# css3 input styling without using background image

Tags: css, input

Can I have the input style in the bellow link with css without using background image?

http://s9.postimg.org/e19w0zn5b/input.gif

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried bud? It might be a good idea to code up an example of what you done so far in a place like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will almost answer your question. It's pure css.

Divs can't have `focus` so I used `hover` instead. You might use JQuery to set different style on focus.

[See code example here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ur2k/)